# Pacman add-repo error, is not a package file

Tags: arm, pacman

I'm using archlinuxarm, armv7h architecture
I'm trying to use `add-repo` but it gives me the following error:

```
$ repo-add test.db.tar.gz dep/python2-numpy-1.9.2-2-armv7h.pkg.tar.xz
==> ERROR: 'dep/blas-3.5.0-1-armv7h.pkg.tar.xz' is not a package file, skipping
==> No packages modified, nothing to do.
```

I've tried it with pacman `v4.1.2-6` and `v.4.2.1`. It fails for every downloaded package that I haven't build myself

Just installing the package with `pacman -U` works absolutely fine

Comment: I'm reproducing this with Pacman 5.1.1 (libalpm v11.0.1) on x86_64, so it's not ARM-specific.

Answer (score 0):

This issue happens when `repo-add` is unable to successfully run

```
bsdtar -tqf dep/python2-numpy-1.9.2-2-armv7h.pkg.tar.xz .PKGINFO
```

`bsdtar` is from `libarchive` package. Ensure that it's available in the PATH, and that the command above succeeds when run by hand for the package in question.